# JavaScript regular expression case insensitivity

Tags: javascript, regex

Please look this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/XCPB6/4).

````
var target = "Thanks For Looking This Problem";
var phrase = ["anks", "for", "king T"];

for(var indx = 0; indx < phrase.length; indx ++)
{
  target = target.replace(new RegExp(phrase[indx], "gi"), "~~~" + phrase[indx]+ "```");
}
​
````

I get this output: ```` Th~~~anks``` ~~~for``` Loo~~~king T```his Problem ````

But I need this output: ```` Th~~~anks``` ~~~For``` Loo~~~king T```his Problem ````

'For' instead of 'for'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) by the phrase, but by the matched string:

````
… target.replace(new RegExp(phrase[indx], "gi"), "~~~$&```");
````

With that, you might as well remove the loop and use only

````
return target.replace(new RegExp(phrase.join("|"), "gi"), "~~~$&```")
````

Comment: thanks. any good tutorial to learn regular expression. because i couldn't find your method in google search.

Comment: The linked docs explains about the replace syntax. To learn using Regexes in JS, you might read [MDN's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), to learn regular expression syntax (and lot more) go with http://www.regular-expressions.info/